# Recuperar dados do Parser.com do tipo ponteiro

Tags: android, parse.com

​Tenho a tabela no banco de dados Parser, que se chama Comentario.

Dentro dela tenho a campo comentario e um campo chamado ponteiro do tipo "ponteiro" que aponta para o objectId de outra tabela que se chama Imagem.
Sendo assim, eu preciso mostrar todos os comentarios que estão relacionado a esta foto.
Estou fazendo desse jeito:

ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comentario");

query.whereEqualTo("ponteiro", obID);

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

**O que estou fazendo de errado? Não mostra nada!**

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comentario");
        query.whereEqualTo("ponteiro", obID);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

```
        public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {//lista com sucesso

               // for (ParseObject object: commentList) {

                 //   Log.i("ListarDados", "Comentario:  " + object.get("comentario"));
                //}
                Log.i("ListarDados"," Sucesso ao listar comentarios"+ commentList.size());


            } else { // lista sem sucesso

                Log.i("ListarDados"," Erro ao listar comentarios"+ e.getMessage());

            }

        }
    });
```

o erro estava em como eu estava salvando no banco de dados!